# Assertion Failure -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext]

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, assertions

I am parsing an xml file and putting its parsed values in a table view.The table view has only one section.But i am getting following exception:

> 2013-10-14 15:21:57.250 tableview[6068:907] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:909
>   2013-10-14 15:22:11.227 tableview[6068:907]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'
>   ** First throw call stack:
>   (0x33e752a3 0x3bcde97f 0x33e7515d 0x3474aab7 0x35cb0a9f 0x35de6b27 0x6a10f 0x69ce5 0x33dc6037 0x346dc599 0x6b54b 0x3478c0f5 0x33e4a683 0x33e49ee9 0x33e48cb7 0x33dbbebd 0x33dbbd49 0x379702eb 0x35cd1301 0x68bdd 0x68b64)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

The code is:

```
/**
 The NSOperation "ParseOperation" calls addFiles: via NSNotification, on the main thread which in turn calls this method, with batches of parsed objects. The batch size is set via the kSizeOfEarthquakeBatch constant.
 */
- (void)addFilesToList:(NSArray *)files {

    NSInteger startingRow = [self.fileList count];
    NSLog(@"STARTING ROW:%d",startingRow);
    NSInteger fileCount = [files count];
    NSLog(@"FILE COUNT : %d",fileCount);
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:fileCount];
    NSLog(@"INDEX PATHS:%@",indexPaths);
    for (NSInteger row = startingRow; row < (startingRow + fileCount); row++) {
        NSLog(@"into for");

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
        NSLog(@"INDEXPAth %@",indexPath);
        [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }

    [self.fileList addObjectsFromArray:files];
    NSLog(@"ADD objects");
    NSLog(@"FILELIST:%@",self.fileList);

    //GETTING EXCEPTION AT THIS LINE

    [self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; 
}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate\

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

// The number of rows is equal to the number of earthquakes in the array.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.fileList count];
    NSLog(@"NUMBER OF ROWS :%d",[self.fileList count]);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *kFileCellID = @"Cell";
    myTableCell *cell = (myTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kFileCellID];

    // Get the specific earthquake for this row.
    fileList *file = (self.fileList)[indexPath.row];

    [cell configureWithFile:file];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case issue was i used two indexPath(indexPath,lastIndexPath). but for lastIndexPath.row had out of my array bound.solve by check condition.hope this help someone.

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, lastIndexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Answer (score 11):

What is happening is that that tableview you are adding the new cell in is still not aware of the changes done to the self.fileList array. The order in which UIKit will add the new cell and check for the section count is unfortunately out of your control.
However in order to fix this problem UItableview insert and delete operations need to be wrapped on beginsUpdate and endsUpdate methods call.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

// Do all the insertRowAtIndexPath and all the changes to the data source array

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was updating rows after an API call.

Try to update rows inside main thread. ( as All UI update should be done inside main thread ).

Try this....

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .bottom)
}
```